# FFMPEG: How to stream to multiple outputs with the same encoding independently

Tags: ffmpeg

How my stream is working right now:

Input:
Switcher program that captures the camera and screen shots and make a different layouts. One of the windows from the software is the one used as Input in the ffmpeg command line.

Output:
- Facebook (example)
- Youtube (example)

At the beginning, i thought that maybe could be better create two different ffmpeg processes to stream independently to each output. The problem was it uses too much CPU.
The answer for it, was to encode one time and copy it to different outputs. Ok, great, it solves the problem, but what if one of the output fails? Both fail.

I'm trying to make one encoding to two outputs and if one of these outputs is not available, the other keep going well.

Anybody have any idea to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution following what @LordNeckbeard said.

Here is a sample code to:

1. Save a local file
2. Stream to your server
3. Stream to Facebook server

Every stream is independent from the other and will try to recover itself independently every one second if something happened like internet connection–will save locally and try to recover when internet access came back–or destination server is not available yet and when it came back it will restart the streaming process):

```
-i ... -f tee "[onfail=ignore]'C:\Users\blablabla.mp4'|
[f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]rtmp://yourServer...|
[f=fifo:fifo_format=flv:drop_pkts_on_overflow=1:attempt_recovery=1:recovery_wait_time=1]"rtmp://facebook..."
```

Comment: Whilst this seems to stream, the media server seems to throw errors when I try and replay back the stream in anything other than RTMP. When I pull the HLS version if it, I get errors like this. `[NULL @ 0x7fd14a810400] pps_id 3199971767 out of range
Invalid UE golomb code=   0 aq=   21KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[NULL @ 0x7fd14a810400] pps_id 3199971767 out of range
Invalid UE golomb code
[NULL @ 0x7fd14a810400] pps_id 3199971767 out of range
Invalid UE golomb code=   0 aq=   21KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0`

Answer (score 4):

Example using the tee muxer with the `onfail` option and also output a local file:

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k -g 50 -f tee "[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://facebook|[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://youtube|[f=segment:strftime=1:segment_time=60]local_%F_%H-%M-%S.mkv"
```

Also see:

- [FFmpeg Documentation: tee muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1)
- [FFmpeg Documentation: segment muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Encoding for Streaming Sites](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites)

Comment: But, if I want to keep trying to send it, it will reload if the output became available?

Comment: Example: If i'm streaming and my internet fail up, I keep saving it locally and when internet come up, I send stream to server again.

Comment: if I restart the command it will restart the local file, which is exactly what I don't want to. :(

Comment: This can be done with RTMP live streaming and a local file? Can you show me an example, is a great idea, but I couldn't find any example.

Comment: @LucasSchoch Example updated to include a segmented local output. I also fixed a typo: `muxrate` has been corrected to `maxrate`. See the [segment muxer docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for a large list of additional options to choose from.

Comment: Is there a way i can specify video bitrate since am getting this
`frame= 2033 fps= 45 q=29.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:01:07.70 bitrate=N/A speed=1.51x   `
Even when i add custom `-b:v 1M` i still get N/A

Comment: @SteveMitto I don't know why it does not report bitrate when using the tee muxer, but it does not mean it is not using your requested bitrate. I tested with local file output and it did use the bitrate I specified although it was not reported in the console output.